# PyCharm not detecting python3 interpretor

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I've created a python3 virtual env. However when I try start a new Django project in PyCharm, it doesn't show up in the list of interpreters. Any idea why?

Comment: in pycharm you can browse and select your virtualenv python interpreter, did you try that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File->Settings->Project->Project interpreter->add local (by clicking on that wheel on the right)

You can also create new from that level.

Comment: Thanks this should work. But do you know which file/dir I select in my virtual env for the interpreter?

Comment: env_name/bin/python(3)